# Yii2 implement 'User Last Seen' update

Tags: yii2

Where would you add a 'last seen' update in the Yii2 framework? I can't do it in LoginForm::login(), because I want it to update every time a user loads a page.

Any tips?

Comment: Have you class something like WebUser in protected/components? Do it in  the class that is responsible for user authorization.

Comment: That was the way to go in Yii 1.x, are you suggesting creating a component that extends from User model and use that as the authentication class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a component called "Controller.php" under app/components folder,

```
<?php

namespace app\components;
use Yii;
use app\models\User;

class Controller extends \yii\web\Controller 
{
    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();

        if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
            // Code to Set the last seen time for the user. For eg,
            $user = User::findOne(Yii::$app->user->id);
            $user->last_seen = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            $user->save(false, ["last_seen"]);
        }
    }
}
```

Now all the controllers used in your app must extend the "Controller" component. For eg,

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use app\components\Controller; //Instead of yii\web\Controller

class SiteController extends Controller
{
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        return $this->render('index');
    }
}
```

This way every time, when a page is loaded, the last seen time will be set.

Comment: Since the value is not entered by the user, validation can be skipped and only `last_seen` should be updated i.e `$user->save(false, ["last_seen"])`. +1

Comment: bad example, add variant with 'on beforeAction' in config

Answer (score 1):

add fild like "activity" to user table

add in config code:

```
    'components'=>[
....
    ],
    'on beforeAction' => function(){
      if(!Yii::$app->user->isGuest){
        \common\models\User::updateAll(['activity'=>time()],['id'=>Yii::$app->user->id]);
      }
    },
```